# html.parser.unescape is returning a strangely encoded string

Tags: python, html, decode, encode, ironpython

I'm baffled at this moment. I'm attempting to decode some HTML encoded test, then split it by a character. However, the encoding that I'm getting from `html.parse.unescape` is making this impossible.

The only time it's formatted 'correctly' is when I print the results, `__repr__` and `__str__` are both in this encoded format.

Here's the sample:

```py
import html.parser


raw_str = '10:20am&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;12:10pm'

decoded_str = html.parser.unescape(raw_str)

print(decoded_str)
print(decoded_str.split('-'))
```

Output:

```
10:20am – 12:10pm
['10:20am\xa0–\xa012:10pm']
```

The output shows that the `decoded_str` is not being split as I expected, and that there are encoded characters present. If we check the type of this value, we get the following:

```py
>>> type(decoded_str)
<class 'str'>
```

`decoded_str` is supposedly a string, and I'm staring at a `-` character in the middle, yet it refuses to split, and these encoded characters are causing all sorts of issues. Last note, I believe that even though the `-` character is being displayed in the above example, that it's actually being decoded from `\u2013` based on my results from an IronPython instance.

Comment: That character is an n-dash, not an ordinary ASCII dash character.

Comment: Use `chr(8211)` instead of `'-'`